# Trying to sign-in Office Add-in via SSO with a guest Azure AD account from another Azure tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, office-js, office-addins

We are developing an Office Add-in, in an Azure VM hosted in our main Azure tenant @ourcompany.com.

The Azure AD App Registration is provisioned in the main Azure tenant.

The Users in the main tenant are licensed to Microsoft 365.

We also have an Azure development tenant @ourcompanydev.onmicrosoft.com with Users who do not have  Microsoft 365 licenses.

These users have been added as external guest Users in the main Azure tenant.

When testing in Postman, all Users from both tenants can authenticate with Azure AD and access the Web App using token acquired via implicit OAuth2 flow.

However when singing into Office SSO with external guest Users, the process fails.

The following Office SSO attempts were made and their outcome

| User | Microsoft 365 License | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1@ourcompany.com | Yes | Success |
| user2@ourcompany.com | No | Success |
| user3@ourcompanydev.onmicrosoft.com | Yes | Failed |
| user4@ourcompanydev.onmicrosoft.com | No | Failed |

The Failed error message is rather ambiguous, to suggest we have our `<WebApplicationInfo>` settings misconfigured but it is not, as the Success scenarios above prove

```
code: 13004
message: "Invalid resource Url specified in the manifest."
name: "Invalid application resource Url provided."
```

Answer (score 1):

**The error "`Invalid resource Url specified in the manifest`" if there is any domain mismatch.**

**AFAIK**, the External users have domain (`@ourcompanydev.onmicrosoft.com`) that does not match the domain of the add-in (`@ourcompany.com`) so you are getting the error code **`13004`**.

- Check whether the manifest has been configured correctly.
- Check whether the resource protocol is **`api`** or not.
- Check whether you have included any **port** in the domain, if yes it should be same as add-in domain.

*Try  [**Validating**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest) your office add-in Manifest.*

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Troubleshoot error messages for single sign-on - Office Add-ins | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins#13004)

[validate-office-addin passes, Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync fails with error 13004  by **Rick-Kirkham**](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/379#issuecomment-422544864)